# Нужно создать ArrayList, элементами которого будет Queue

Tags: java, list, очередь

У меня не получается инициализировать его.

```
ArrayList<Queue<Pair>> colors = new ArrayList<Queue<Pair>>();
colors.ensureCapacity(l+1);
colors.get(0).add(new Pair(1, 1, 0));
```

Ругается на последнюю строчку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы запрашиваете первый элемент, которого нет, и пытаетесь у него вызвать метод `add`.

Что-то вроде такого:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

...

static class Pair {
    public Pair(int a, int b, int c) {}
}

... 

ArrayList<Queue<Pair>> colors = new ArrayList<Queue<Pair>>();
colors.add(new LinkedList());
colors.get(0).add(new Pair(1, 1, 0));
```

---

**PS.**

`Queue` – интерфейс, поэтому нельзя создавать его объекты, а нужно использовать классы, реализующие данный интерфейс.

Comment: а как их объявить. Можете пример, пожалуйста?